# autoselect time from timepicker if current time match with timepicker values, every 5 minutes compare current time with time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, setinterval, timepicker

I am using timepicker jquery plugin and it will show time with interval of 5 minutes, now my requirement is check current time and if current time match with time picker values than timepicker  value should highlight automatically in text box

you can find link at here https://jsfiddle.net/waeqf7n2/

Expected output

if current time is 11:05 AM then it should autoselect and display that time from time picker and after 5 minutes it should again autoselect 11:10 AM and like this every 5 minutes compare current time with time picker value and autoselect timepicker value

```js
    
    $('.timepicker').timepicker({
        timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
        interval: 5,
        defaultTime: '11',
        startTime: '12:00 am',
        dynamic: true,
        dropdown: true,
        scrollbar: true,
     
    });
    
    
    setInterval(function(){ 
    
    const date = new Date();
    const options = {
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: 'numeric',
      hour12: true
    };
    const time = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(date);
    
    if($('.timepicker').val()===time)
    {
     alert('time matched');
    }
    else{
    //console.log(time);
    }
    
    }, 3000);
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" id="jt-homepage-demo-start-time" name="startTime" >
```